# Get the newest file from non-current directory

Tags: unix, shell, filesystems

I am having trouble executing a command which will give me the latest file from another directory.

Example:

```
ls -tr | tail -n 1  /prj/somedir/anotherdir/closerdir/targetdir
```

there is a list of files in the `targetdir` and I need to isolate the newest file from the list.

When I type in the command the problem is that I am using the tail command for a directory.

Example 2:

```
ls -tr | tail -n 1
```

Using the `tail` command works if I am trying to get the newest file from the directory I am working in but not if I am trying to consume from another directory using the absolute path.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify a shell, so I advise you to use [Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/):

```
ls /path/to/*(.om[1])
```

Here's an example with five file that were all created in the same minute (filenames in the form `HHMMSS.txt`):

```
> ls tmp/378142 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   7 johnsyweb  staff  238 14 Jan 08:23 ./
drwx------  24 johnsyweb  staff  816 14 Jan 08:20 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 johnsyweb  staff    0 14 Jan 08:22 082237.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 johnsyweb  staff    0 14 Jan 08:22 082238.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 johnsyweb  staff    0 14 Jan 08:22 082239.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 johnsyweb  staff    0 14 Jan 08:22 082240.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 johnsyweb  staff    0 14 Jan 08:22 082241.txt
```

Using `echo`:

```
> echo tmp/378142/*(.om[1])
tmp/378142/082241.txt
```

Using `ls`:

```
> ls -laF tmp/378142/*(.om[1]) 
-rw-r--r--  1 johnsyweb  staff  0 14 Jan 08:22 tmp/378142/082241.txt
```

### Explanation:

This uses Zsh's [filename expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion).

An asterisk expands to all items in a directory:

```
> echo tmp/378142/*        
tmp/378142/082237.txt tmp/378142/082238.txt tmp/378142/082239.txt tmp/378142/082240.txt tmp/378142/082241.txt
```

Modifying this with a `.`, means all regular files (no directories or symlinks). This is known as a [globbing flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Globbing-Flags):

```
> echo tmp/378142/*(.)  
tmp/378142/082237.txt tmp/378142/082238.txt tmp/378142/082239.txt tmp/378142/082240.txt tmp/378142/082241.txt
```

`o` specifies the sort order, `on`, is by name:

```
> echo tmp/378142/*(.on)
tmp/378142/082237.txt tmp/378142/082238.txt tmp/378142/082239.txt tmp/378142/082240.txt tmp/378142/082241.txt
```

`om` is sorts by modified time (`Om`) would reverse the order:

```
> echo tmp/378142/*(.om)
tmp/378142/082241.txt tmp/378142/082240.txt tmp/378142/082239.txt tmp/378142/082238.txt tmp/378142/082237.txt
```

`[1]` selects the first item in the list:

```
> echo tmp/378142/*(.om[1])
tmp/378142/082241.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear about what you want. If you want the name of the most recent file in a directory

```
  ls -t /prj/somedir/anotherdir/closerdir/targetdir | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /your/path -type f -exec ls -l \{\} \;
```

Should give you a nice start (only files are listed with verbose `ls` output. Not just sort the output and print the necessary line.

Comment: Thanks Zsolt! Is there anyway to add a command to this that would display only the latest and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple - you need to put the path to the directory in question right after the `ls -t` command or else `ls` will think you mean the current directory. Then `head` will read the piped output from `ls` and echo the top line. Hence, the confusion. Then it's just a matter of doing it right:

```
$ ls -t /prj/somedir/anotherdir/closerdir/targetdir | head -n 1
```